# Codename one URLImage doesn't display the new image

Tags: codenameone

I have a scenario, where I have to take a picture of the user and save it to amazon cloud (Shai had guided me well on saving the image to amazon s3 bucket - Thank you.)
Now that I can save the image and I am using URLImage to show the user profile picture on log in. I am not seeing the picture at all instead I do see the image that was cached very first time.

```
//Imagename is follows: customerId.jpg (e.g. 123456.jpg)
Image urlImg = URLImage.createToStorage(placeHolder, "123456.jpg", imageUrl);
```

I have used a label and to show the image(I don't know if I am doing the right thing)

```
label.setIcon(ulImg);
```

I still see the very first image I saved to s3 bucket.  I did check the bucket and I do see the new image has been saved with customerId.jpg (123456.jpg).
I want to achieve the following.  Once new picture taken it should be displayed when user logs back in instead of showing the very first picture that was taken.
Is there any way I can refresh the image?  Please advise what is the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refresh the image by deleting the cached storage file. In this case `123456.jpg`. To do this just use:

```
Storage.getInstance().deleteStorageFile("123456.jpg");
```

Then recreating the image will re-fetch it.

Comment: Shai, I made the changes and I added round mask to show round image.  All looked perfect on the simulator.  
Once I sent the code to build and deployed on iPhone the image is not displaying.  Please advise.
Thanks,

Comment: I suggest asking a new question including details of how you've set the round mask?

Comment: Shai, I was able to figure out the issue, It was my mistake I didn't notice that the image url wasn't https.  I changed to https and I did see the image.

I have another question and I'll create a new thread.

Thanks,